# JDialog/OptionPane with big custom buttons with icons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jdialog

I am relatively new to Java and I'm struggling to get something like in the following picture, the background colors of the buttons do not matter, they are just colored to show that they are different:

[image]

Comment: @AndrewThompson your first comment answered it perfectly, I tried to just add Buttons directly to the JDialog all the time. If you post your comment as answer I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout would be a `GridLayout` (with spacing also set in the constructor). Create a `JPanel` to use the grid layout in. Add the panel to a `JDialog`.

Job done.